# How to combine multiple dataframe values having set of common column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` which consists of string values in `ColA`, These `ColA` values will have duplicates as shown.

Now my `df2` will have same set of values in `ColA`, which are not repeated. So I want to append the `ColD` values of `df2` to my original `df1`. (60 will repeat twice for app, 20 will repeat thrice..and so on..). Similarly I want to append `ColE` values of `df3` to my `df1`

Can it be done by transposing `ColA` so it becomes column names and then can we append values to it,  or can the `ColA` be set as indexes and then we need to append values, or is there any other way?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import io

data1='''
ColA,ColB,ColC
app,5,2
app,6,3
book,10,6
book,4,8
book,9,0
car,7,8
car,1,3
'''

data2='''
ColA,ColD
app,60
book,20
car,8
'''

data3='''
ColA,ColE
app,3
book,6
car,9
'''

df1=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data1))
df2=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data2))
df3=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data3))
```

Expected output: `df1`

```
ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE
app     5    2   60    3
app     6    3   60    3
book   10    6   20    6
book    4    8   20    6
book    9    0   20    6
car     7    8    8    9
car     1    3    8    9
```

Comment: I think Jerzael's answer from this post would do the trick actually. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34674499/9375102

Comment: @G.Anderson yes..it did work...My bad for the duplicate..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `merge`:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='ColA', how='left').merge(df3, on='ColA', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   ColA  ColB  ColC  ColD  ColE
0   app     5     2    60     3
1   app     6     3    60     3
2  book    10     6    20     6
3  book     4     8    20     6
4  book     9     0    20     6
5   car     7     8     8     9
6   car     1     3     8     9
```